# I need an array, where user introduce 10 values and print changing the elements position +1, without functions

Tags: python

I'm in my first steps in python: I need an array, where user introduce 10 values and print changing the elements position +1, without functions.

Input: 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
Output: **1** 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 **2**

I don't know how following after..

```
v=[0]*10

for i in range (0,10):
    v[i] = (input())
```

Comment: `print(*v[1:], *v[:1])`?

Comment: the problem ask to move one position up, I mean, the first becomes the second, the third the fourth, and the last on the list becomes the first:

example: 
Input:
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
output:
1 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2

Comment: done! thanks for your help Sayse!
v=[0]*10
for i in range (0,10):
    v[i] = (input())
v = (*v[9:], *v[:9])
for i in range (0,10):
    print (v[i])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
outputs = []
outputs.append(inputs[-1])
outputs.extend(inputs[:-1])
```

```
outputs >>> [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```